# Get different columns of each row from matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Matrix `A = [19,20,30; 41,54,65; 72,83,95]`

Matrix `B = [2,3; 1,3; 3,3]`

Output Matrix `C = [20; 30; 41; 54; 65; 95]`

Matrix `B` includes which columns should be transferred to output matrix `C`. For example, second row of `B` is `1` and `3`. So from second row of `A`; elements between 1st and 3rd column should be transferred to output matrix `C`.

Without for loop, only with matrix operations, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (and Matlab works in column major order), transpose `A` first. Then build a logical mask to be used as index into `A` transposed:

```
At = A.'; %'
mask = (bsxfun(@ge, (1:size(At,1)), B(:,1)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:size(At,1), B(:,2))).'; %'
result = At(mask);
```

Comment: Thanks Luis. It works for square matrix perfectly. But in my real study, A is not a square matrix. So it returned "Inputs must have the same size." error.

Comment: @oarar Corrected. Please try now